# Prove $\int_a^b f(x)dx \leq \frac{e^{2L\beta}-1}{2L\alpha}\int_c^d f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, inequality, integral-inequality, lipschitz-functions

Assume $f(x)>0$ defined in $[a,b]$, and for a certain $L>0$, $f(x)$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq L|x_1-x_2|$.

Assume that for $a\leq c\leq d\leq b$,$$\int_c^d \frac{1}{f(x)}dx=\alpha,\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx=\beta$$Try to prove$$\int_a^b f(x)dx \leq \frac{e^{2L\beta}-1}{2L\alpha}\int_c^d f(x)dx$$

Comment: Is this homework? It's stated as if it were something akin to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got something which is rather close to your result but couldn't get rid of an additional term. I'm hoping someone will find the development useful in order to give a complete answer. The question reminded me somehow of the proof of Gronwall's inequality and my answer is based on that.

Let $h(t)=\int_a^t f(s)ds$ taking the derivative with respect to $t$ yields
$h'(t) = f(t)$. Rewriting $f(t)=f^2(t)/f(t)$, we can find an upper bound for $f^2(t)$ indeed, we have:
$$f^2(t) = \int_a^t (f^2(s))'ds + f^2(a) = 2\int_a^t f(s)f'(s)ds +f^2(a)$$

but then, the Lipschitz continuity implies that $|f'(s)|\le L$ which yields

$$f^2(t) \le 2L \int_a^t f(s)ds + f^2(a)\quad \Longrightarrow \quad h'(t) \le \left(2Lh(t) +f^2(a)\right)\left({1\over f(t)}\right) $$
we can then introduce the additional positive term $\left(\int_c^df(t)dt\right)/\alpha$ with:
$$ h'(t) \le \left(2L h(t)+f^2(a) + {\int_c^d f(s)ds\over \alpha}\right)\left({1\over f(t)}\right) $$
**Remark**: the additional term comes from the $f^2(a)$. We could get rid of it if $\left(\int_c^d f(s)ds\right)/\alpha > f^2(a)$ which I wasn't able to prove.

To simplify notations, let $a=f^2(a) + {\int_c^d f(s)ds\over \alpha},$ $b=2L$ and $g(t)=1/f(t)$ then. Then the previous inequality reads
$$h'(t) \le g(t)(a+bh(t))$$
which can be rewritten as follows (here is where it starts to look like Gronwall's inequality):

$$ {(a+bh(t))'\over a+bh(t)} \le bg(t) $$

the left-hand side is the logarithmic derivative of $a+bh(t)$, integrating both sides from $a$ to $t$ yields

$$ a+bh(t) \le a\exp\left(b\int_a^t g(t) \right) $$

plugging the values of $a$,$b$ and using $\int_a^b g(t) = \beta$, we finally get:

$$\int_a^b f(s)ds = h(b) \le \color{green}{\left[{\exp(2L\beta)-1\over 2L\alpha}\right]\int_c^d f(s)ds} + \color{red}{{f^2(a)\over 2L}\left(\exp(2L\beta)-1\right)} $$

Comment: 1.h′(t)=f(t).2.The main problem is that I don't assume that f is derivable.So you may have to improve your method.Thanks.

Comment: Yes but I believe that the Lipschitz continuity of $f$ implies that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere (I believe that this is called Lebesgue's theorem) and that $$\left(f(b)-f(a)\right)=\int_a^b f'(t)dt$$ I agree however that the development can certainly be made more rigorous but the idea was rather to suggest a possible method.

Comment: Since it is a bounty question,I hope that you can show me a rigorous proof. Thanks. Anyway, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is smooth, or $f\in C^1$, assume $\displaystyle h(t)=\int_a^t f(s)\mathrm{d}s$, and $\displaystyle g(t)=\int_a^{t}\frac{1}{f(s)}\mathrm{d}s$,we just can focus on 
\begin{equation}
\frac{h(t)}{\exp(2Lg(t)-1)}
\end{equation}

because we know that there is a $\xi\in(c,d)$ s.t. 
\begin{equation}
\frac{h(d)-h(c)}{g(d)-g(c)}=\frac{h'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}=f^2(\xi)
\end{equation}

thus we just prove
$$\frac{h(t)}{\exp(2Lg(t)-1)}\le\frac{\min_{[a,b]}f^2(\xi)}{2L}$$

To find the minimum. Let's compute the derivative and we also can see the LHS function at $t=a$ has a limit as $f^2(a)/2L$.

Assume the LHS term is $\gamma(t)$, then
\begin{equation}
\gamma'(t)=\frac{h'(\exp(2Lg)-1)-2Lg'\exp(2Lg)h}{(\exp(2Lg)-1)^2}
\end{equation}

It is easy to compute the limit at $t=a$, we find that $\gamma'(a)=\frac{f(a)f'(a)}{2L}-\frac{1}{2}f(a)\le0$.
And we shall see that if we set
\begin{eqnarray}
p(t)&=&f\cdot(h'(\exp(2Lg)-1)-2Lg'\exp(2Lg)h)\\
&=&f^2(\exp(2Lg)-1)-2L\exp(2Lg)h
\end{eqnarray}

We can see that $p(a)=0$, since $h(a)=0$ and $g(a)=0$. However, 
\begin{eqnarray}
p'(t)&=&2ff'(\exp(2Lg)-1)-4L^2\exp(2Lg)h/f\\
&\le&\frac{2L}{f}(f^2(\exp(2Lg)-1)-2L\exp(2Lg)h)\\
&=&\frac{2L}{f}p(t)
\end{eqnarray}

Thus we shall know that $p(t)\le 0$, since $\{(\exp(-2Lg(t))p\}'\le0$,and $p(a)=0$.

So we shall get that $\gamma'(t)\le 0$.

Thus $\gamma$ is decreasing in $t$, $\gamma(t)\le\gamma(a)$.

On the other hand. Take $\displaystyle\int_{t}^b f(s)\mathrm{d}s=\phi(t)$,$\displaystyle\int_{t}^b\frac{1}{f(s)}\mathrm{d}s=\psi(t)$.

Then we also can see that 
\begin{equation}
\beta(t)=\frac{\phi(t)}{\exp(2L\psi(t)-1)}
\end{equation}
which has $\displaystyle\beta(b)=\frac{f^2(b)}{2L}.$

with the same process(PAY ATTENTION TO THE SIGN),
$$\beta'(b)=\frac{f(b)f'(b)}{2L}+\frac{f(b)}{2}\ge 0.$$

And also we can obtain that 
$$q(t)=2L \exp(2L \psi)\phi-f^2(\exp(2L\psi)-1)\ge 0$$

which means $\beta(t)$ is increasing in $t$, which is $\beta(t)\le\beta(b)$.

Since $\beta(a)=\gamma(b)$, thus $\gamma(b)\le \min(f^2(a),f^2(b))/2L$.

AND the choice of $b$ is arbitrary, we know that for any $t$, we have
$$\gamma(t)\le f^2(t)/2L$$

Consider the $\min_{[a,b]}f^2(t)$ is reached at $t=\upsilon$, then
$\gamma(\upsilon)\le f^2(\upsilon)/2L$, since $\gamma(t)$ is decreasing in $t$.
Thus $\gamma(b)\le f^2(\upsilon)/2L$.
$\Box$

Comment: When $f$ is Lip. I think one can apply convolution to it to make it smooth. And we can approximate both sides.

Comment: 1. I don't understand how you obtain the inequality $\gamma(t) \leq \frac{f(t)^2}{2L}$ "since the choice of $b$ is arbitrary". When $t$ varies, $\gamma(a)$ stays $\gamma(a)$.

Comment: 2. How do you obtain $\gamma(b) \leq \frac{f(v)^2}{2L}$ from $\gamma(v) \leq \frac{f(v)^2}{2L}$ ? You can't just replace $\gamma(v)$ with $\gamma(b)$.

Comment: for your last question, since $\gamma$ is decreasing. I proved one thing the integral. If you consider $a$ and $b$ are both variables, then $\gamma(a,b,t)\le\min(\gamma(a,b,a),\gamma(a,b,b))$

Comment: You shall see the definition of $\gamma$, it is $h(t)/\exp(2Lg(t)-1)$, in which, $h$ and $g$ are integrals from $a$ to $t$. thus if for $b\ge a$, we have $h(t)/\exp(2Lg(t))-1)\le f^2(b)/2L$,for any $t\in[a,b]$, we should have the same thing if we consider $b$ as a variable.

Comment: I understand what you mean, it was a typo. I corrected it, Now it makes sense.

Comment: With your corrected version, I am now convinced that $\gamma(t) \leq \frac{f^2(t)}{2L}$.

Comment: But your corrected version does not answer my question 2 : at the last line, you still appear to magically (and falsely) replace $\gamma(v)$ with $\gamma(b)$.

Comment: because $\gamma$ is decreasing, thus $\gamma(b)\le\gamma(\upsilon)$. Since $\upsilon\le b$.

Comment: Right. I think you've answered everything now, thanks for taking the time to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's commence by defining $m = f(x_0) = \min f(x)$, which implies the following inequality:

$$m\le f(x)\le m+L|x-x_0|$$

From this, we can establish the following relationships:

\begin{align*}
\beta=\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\ge \int_a^b\frac{1}{m+L|x-x_0|}dx&=\frac{1}{L}\ln\left(1+\frac{L}{m}(b-a)+\frac{L^2}{m^2}(b-x_0)(x_0-c)\right)\\
&\ge\frac{1}{L}\ln\left(1+\frac{L}{m}(b-a)\right)
\end{align*}
and
$$\alpha=\int_c^d\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\le\int_c^d\frac{1}{m}dx=\frac{d-c}{m}$$

These inequalities illustrate the relationships between the lengths of the two intervals and the two parameters:

$$b-a\le \frac{m}{L}\left(e^{L\beta}-1\right)$$
$$d-c\ge m\alpha$$

Moving forward, we can consider the following:

\begin{align*}
\int_a^b f(x)dx\le\int_a^b\left(m+L|x-x_0|\right)dx&=m(b-a)+L\left(\left(x_0-\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2\right)\\
&\le m(b-a)+\frac{L}{2}(b-a)^2\le \frac{e^{2L\beta}-1}{2L}m^2
\end{align*}

and

$$\int_c^df(x)dx\ge\int_c^dmdx=m(d-c)\ge \alpha m^2$$

These calculations ultimately yield the expected inequality:

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\le \frac{e^{2L\beta}-1}{2L\alpha}\int_c^df(x)dx$$